# How can I set click event on items in ToolBar?

Tags: java, android-studio

What I want to do is that, when the user clicks the toolbar, the layout will change.

On the code below, the toolbar is working correctly on StartActivity and design defined by main_menu.xml.

How can I implement click event of the toolbar?
If anyone knows, please help.

↓StartActivity

```html
Button b = findViewById(R.id.action_add_contact);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                menuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

↓menu_main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_add_contact"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:title="Add contact"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" >
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_cut"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
        android:title="Cut"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_copy"

        android:title="Test"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_paste"

        android:title="222"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

↓Layout inside activity_start.xml

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/layout_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ItemSelected

```html
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_item1:
                Intent i = new Intent(StartActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;//this item has your app icon
            case R.id.menu_item2:
                //↓This Line is not wroking
                menuLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item).setEnabled(false);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```